# method resolution when instantiating an interface

Tags: java

EDIT: FORGOT THE CODE SNIPPET _ ADDED HERE

I am trying to learn Java from the book 'Learning Java' that has the following code snippet listed as an example for interface callbacks. In this code snippet, there is only 1 class implementing the interface TextReceiver. My question is - since this code is instantiating the interface directly, if there was another class that implemented the interface **TextReceiver** and provided a whole different method body to the interface method receivetext than the one in TickerTape, then how would java resolve the reference to the method receivetext in the sendText method of TextSource? This seems like it would introduce ambiguity - also, it seems credence to what I have seen online about not being able to instantiate interfaces - but wanted to confirm before assuming

> ```
> interface TextReceiver {
>     void receiveText( String text );
> }
>
> class TickerTape implements TextReceiver {
>     public void receiveText( String text ) {
>         System.out.println("TICKER:\n" + text + "\n");
>     }
> }
>
> class TextSource {
>     TextReceiver receiver;
>
>     TextSource( TextReceiver r ) {
>         receiver = r;
>     }
>
>     public void sendText( String s ) {
>         receiver.receiveText( s );
>     }
> }
> ```

I tried just writing this up myself to figure this out, but got stuck with issues compiling since all of these classes were in the same class. I know this sounds n00bish - but I figured you guys might have quick guidance to offer.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should look into polymorphism. Your book definitely has a chapter on this. Just keep reading.

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: "since this code is instantiating the interface directly" --> No it isn't, it's instantiating a class that implements the interface. There isn't any ambiguity, as the implementation is decided by the object that you call the method on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java interfaces cannot be instantiated, the programmer has to specify what implementation of the interface he wants to instantiate.

For example, if you try to do this (replace INTERFACE with the name of the interface):

```
INTERFACE i = new INTERFACE();
```

you will get an error, because an interface cannot be instantiated.

What you must do is (replace IMPLEMENTATION with the name of the implementation of the interface):

```
INTERFACE i = new IMPLEMENTATION();
```

As you can see, you ALWAYS tell the program what implementation to use for an interface. There's no room for ambiguity.

In your example, the class TextSource is NOT instantating the interface TextReceiver (instantiation occurs with the **"new"** keyword). Instead, it has a constructor that receives the implementation of the interface as a parameter. Therefore, when you call TextSource you MUST tell it what implementation of TextReceiver to use.

Comment: GOT IT! Thanks Zenadix! I didnt pay (enough) attention to that the class did not instantiate the interface, and that it required the construction to provide a specific implementation of the interface as an argument - which resolves the ambiguity!

Answer (score 2):

Methods are dispatched at runtime by looking at the actual type of the object instance.

So if you have

```
 TextReceiver one =  new SomeTextReceiver();
 TextReceiver two =  new SomeCompletelyDifferentTextReceiver();
```

and then call

```
 one.receiveText();
```

the JVM will look at the actual object and see what class it is of.

The call will be dispatched to the implementation provided by that runtime class.

At *compile-time* all that is known here is the interface, so the compiler will check that such a method exists in the interface, but at *run-time* the actual class can be determined and dispatched to.

Note that this process is different for static methods. Those do not have an associated instance and the compiler does decide which implementation to call. As a result, you cannot really override static methods to get runtime dispatch.

Comment: +1.  I always find it worth mentioning in these scenarios that this is the reason `getClass()` can work at all.  Usually ends up being pretty intuitive for new programmers.